# Code Works on Excel 2016 but not works for 2010

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have created this below code which works on Excel 2016 but do not work on Excel 2010 an error appear that is `run time error 13 type mismatch vba` on `Set doc = ie.document`.

But i am unable to figure it out for Excel 2010 how it will fix.

One more thing i want to make it work faster then now. I will appreciate any help.

```
Sub Link()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ecoll As Object
Dim ecolla As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim t As Date

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

t = Now()
'MsgBox "Do you want to initialize this COOL Scraper?"

For i = 2 To lastrow

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
    
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  
    Set doc = ie.document


    Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("rso")
    Set ecolla = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
    Set link = ecolla.parentNode
    On Error Resume Next
    str_text = Replace(link.innerText, link.href, "")
    On Error Resume Next
    str_text = Replace(str_text, " ", "")
    
    
    Cells(i, 2) = link.href
    DoEvents
    
    Next
    ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing


Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Ellapsed Time - " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you see the google page you try accessing in the opened Internet Explorer window? And, in order to make the code faster, do not use IE, anymore...

Comment: Yes when Google Page is opened then error pop up. Alright will try to know how to go for other browser.

Comment: Please, try declaring it as `Dim doc As Object`.

Comment: I already did if use `Dim doc As Object` then error comes to this line `Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("rso")` that is `error 424 Object Required`

Comment: Does the page you show in IE looks **exactly as you expect it to be**?

Comment: Yes I have this `Telemedicine Partners` value in `Range A2` same value is searched by google in the tab then error appear, But after changing `Doc to Object` direct error appear do not opens any window

Comment: I cannot get you. That change does not influence at all what happens in IE...

Comment: When i declare variable `Dim doc As Object` then IE open with same searching criteria then error appear `error 424 Object Required`

Comment: **Where** such an error does appear? I mean on which code line? **does the page you expected to be in the IE window**? I do not think that your problem is Excel version related. I am afraid that the cells you are using keep wrong values against the necessary ones...

Comment: on this line `Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("rso")` "does the page you expected to be in the IE window `yes`"  I really do not understand how this can happen.

Comment: If it keeps the wrong value then how all the values return with result in `2016` that's the problem

Comment: I still do not think that the same workbook will return correctly in 2016... Please paste here the value you use for `Cells(i, 1)`. Is the same big interval used in `RandBetween(1, 10000)`?

Comment: Same problem here. I read articles for Early late binding but all is usekless

Comment: Am on Excel 2010 here, cannot reproduce your issue. Is the Excel 2016 and Excel 2010 on the same machine? If not then I suspect your mshtml.dll might be the issue in the Excel 2010 machine.

Comment: Hi thanks for being here. No  both are on different machines. then how to fix this.

Comment: @HafizSh To be honest - I have no idea (it can also be an issue on your IE?) so I posted an alternative method, hope it works on your machine!

Comment: Thank your alternative works very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not work on your machine but try using `XMLHTTP`, if it works then all the better since it's faster without having to open a browser:

```
Sub link()
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ecoll As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim t As Date
    
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    t = Now()
    'MsgBox "Do you want to initialize this COOL Scraper?"
    
    Dim reqObj As Object
    Set reqObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    For i = 2 To lastrow
            
        reqObj.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000), False
        reqObj.send
        
        doc.body.innerHTML = reqObj.responseText
        
    
        Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("rso")
        Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            
        Cells(i, 2) = link.href
    Next
    
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set reqObj = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox "Ellapsed Time - " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have been stuck again now new error is appearing that is @Raymond Wu https://ibb.co/vY1C6Xw I do not know literally.

Comment: How many search did you do when that occured? Perhaps there are too many requests in a short period so google block it @HafizSh

Comment: Thank you for help you provided i think issue is in my installed office version and the error is unknown. This only can be the reason

Comment: Here is the error https://ibb.co/8m38pZc on the line `Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)`

Comment: @HadizSh unforunately I have no idea what is your issue since it worked before but not anymore.